# meaning of the verse - yugapad jñānā utpatti manaso liṅgam

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, translation-request, meaning

what does the shloka mean

> yugapad jñānā utpatti manaso liṅgam

> युगपत ज्ञाना उत्पत्ति मनसो लिंगम

meaning of each words:

- युगपत (Yugapat): Simultaneously or together.
- ज्ञाना (Jnana): Knowledge or wisdom.
- उत्पत्ति (Utpatti): Origin or emergence.
- मनसो (Manaso): Of the mind.
- लिंगम (Lingam): Symbol or characteristic.

I am not able to come up with an overall meaning for this?

any help is appreciated

Comment: *Simultaneous knowledge is the characteristics of the mind*